# Como chamar uma função logo após um efeito de slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar a altura de uma div e remidensionar um ifram de acordo com a altura atual, até ai tudo bem.

Só que eu estou pegando a altura logo após um clique que dá um slideToggle nessa div. E me parece que como ainda o efeito de slide não terminou eu não consigo obter a altura correta.

Então como consigo chamar essa função somente após o slide estiver completo?

```
$(document).on("click", "#toggleDiv" function(){
    $("#questao").slideToggle(300);
    // chamar função para pegar altura somente após o fim do slide. como?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) aceita uma *callback*, ou seja uma funcão que deve correr quando a animação terminar.

Podes usar assim:

```
$(document).on("click", "#toggleDiv" function(){
    $("#questao").slideToggle(300, function(){
        // aqui o slide já acabou
    });

});
```

Dentro dessa função podes usar o `this` para acessar  elemento animado. Se quiseres a altura podes usar `$(this).height();`